# How to enable PKCE flow in Swagger YML

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, okta, pkce, api-doc

We use Swagger YML for the API documentation. In swagger YML we can specify the authentication flow in the securitySchemes Is there any way that we can enable authorizationCode flow with PKCE in the yml. I know this can be possible with swagger config.

```
securitySchemes:
 TestFlow:
   type: oauth2
   flows:
     authorizationCode:
       authorizationUrl: https://okta.com/oauth2/asxa/v1/authorize
       tokenUrl: https://okta.com/oauth2/dss/v1/token
       scopes:
         openid: openid
```

From this https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7862 I think it's possible with config but is it possible to do it in the yml where we have the API defination itself ?